# Comparing dates with Query Builder

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I am trying to add a parameter `addWhere` in my `Query Builder` that will make it retrieve a date similar to today's date (matching the month and day). My dates stored in `Database` looks like `1895-04-14 00:00:00`, so if today is `14-04` regardless the year it will give me this record. Here's what I've got so far.

```
->select('r')
->where('r.status = :status')
->setParameter(':status', 1)
->andWhere('r.dateOfDeath = :now')
->setParameter('now',\date("m-d", time()))
->getQuery();
 return $qb->getArrayResult();
```

How can I get all the entries from the database matching today's day and month?

Answer (score 0):

since the querybuilder should accept native SQL-code:

```
->andWhere('r.dateOfDeath >= NOW()')
```

should work...

or

```
->setParameter('now', (new \DateTime()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')))
```

if you are using php 5.4 or higher should also work

Comment: the problem is **dateOfDeath** formated in `Y-m-d H:i:s` i need just to see if today `m-d` are equal to **dateOfDeath**  `m-d`

Comment: You should enclose your instance with braces, then use a formatter, cause right now, it seems like you chain the method after **setParameter**.